# Select from table where names have same initial letters

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been looking for a solution for this in SQL. I am trying to find records from one table that has the same first two characters and same birth date. I thought about doing self-join but I doubt I am getting the right results. Here is my query, please tell me what's missing:

```
select p1.frst_name,
from person p1 inner join person p2
on upper(left(p1.frst_name,2)) like upper(left(p2.frst_name,2))
and upper(p1.last_name) LIKE upper(p2.last_name)
and p1.birth_date = p2.birth_date
```

Comment: is this oracle or mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Change `LIKE` to `=` (you want an exact match), and add a join condition to prevent rows from joining to themselves:

```
select p1.id, p1.frst_name, p1.last_name, p1.birth_date
from person p1
join person p2
on upper(left(p1.frst_name,2)) = upper(left(p2.frst_name,2))
and upper(p1.last_name) = upper(p2.last_name)
and p1.birth_date = p2.birth_date
and p1.id != p2.id
```

Without the addition of `and p1.id != p2.id`, every row would be returned, because of course every row would otherwise match itself.

---

The question was tagged with both mysql and oracle. The above query works in mysql. For iracle, which doesn't support `left(col, 2)`, use `substr(col, 1, 2)` instead.

Comment: I wasn't sure about oracle and left(), so I tried it.  I now disagree with your last sentence.

Comment: @DanBracuk ok I've added a note at the bottom re Oracle's lack of support for a pretty basic, amd sql standard, function. Thx for bringing my attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

Join on the last_name and birth_date since you want those to match exactly, then filter by the two first two characters matching.

You shouldn't need upper() on p1.frst_name or p2.frst_name. Because they are the same column in the same table, their cases will match.

Try...

```
select p1.frst_name,
  from person p1 
  full outer join person p2
    on p1.last_name = p2.last_name
   and p1.birth_date = p2.birth_date
 where upper(left(p1.frst_name,2)) like upper(left(p2.frst_name,2))
```

Comment: Your second paragraph is not necessarily true.

Comment: Ah, would this be just because there could be (and according to OP, should be) different records with the same last name and birthday? Or is there something else I'm missing?